# tvOS: Video Player not Pushing to Top of Navigation Stack

Tags: javascript, tvos, tvml

I have a video streaming app I'm working on that lets me select a year of videos from a listTemplate, where each year is then a catalogTemplate with links to video resources. Navigation between the listTemplate and catalogTemplate works fine, but when I select a video from one of the catalogTemplates, the video plays *behind* the template, rather than going to the foreground. How can I fix what I presume is a navigation stack error like this? Below is the code I use to actually present stuff, taken partly from Apple's documentation.

```
load: function(event) {
      console.log(event);

      var self = this,
          ele = event.target,
          templateURL = ele.getAttribute("template"),
          presentation = ele.getAttribute("presentation"),
          videoURL = ele.getAttribute("videoURL");

      if(videoURL) {
        //2
        var player = new Player();
        var playlist = new Playlist();
        var mediaItem = new MediaItem("video", videoURL);

        player.playlist = playlist;
        player.playlist.push(mediaItem);
        player.present();
      };

      /*
      Check if the selected element has a 'template' attribute. If it does then we begin
      the process to present the template to the user.
      */
      if (templateURL) {
          /*
          Whenever a user action is taken you need to visually indicate to the user that
          you are processing their action. When a users action indicates that a new document
          should be presented you should first present a loadingIndicator. This will provide
          the user feedback if the app is taking a long time loading the data or the next 
          document.
          */
          self.showLoadingIndicator(presentation);

          /* 
          Here we are retrieving the template listed in the templateURL property.
          */
          resourceLoader.loadResource(templateURL,
              function(resource) {
                  if (resource) {
                      /*
                      The XML template must be turned into a DOMDocument in order to be 
                      presented to the user. See the implementation of makeDocument below.
                      */
                      var doc = self.makeDocument(resource);

                      /*
                      Event listeners are used to handle and process user actions or events. Listeners
                      can be added to the document or to each element. Events are bubbled up through the
                      DOM heirarchy and can be handled or cancelled at at any point.

                      Listeners can be added before or after the document has been presented.

                      For a complete list of available events, see the TVMLKit DOM Documentation.
                      */
                      doc.addEventListener("select", self.load.bind(self));
                      // doc.addEventListener("highlight", self.load.bind(self));


                      /*
                      This is a convenience implementation for choosing the appropriate method to 
                      present the document. 
                      */
                      if (self[presentation] instanceof Function) {
                          self[presentation].call(self, doc, ele);
                      } else {
                          self.defaultPresenter.call(self, doc);
                      }
                  }
              }
          );
      }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea: `templateURL` is still pointing to a valid address, thus the lower portion of your shown function will directly add an overlay to your video?

Verify (or make sure) to have only one of the two options (`videoURL`, `templateURL`) set. Or only run the `loadResource()` part if no `videoURL` was seen before. Like...

```
if(videoURL) {
    ...
} else if (templateURL) {
    ...
}
```